# Extract object after watershed segmentation

Tags: c++, opencv, extract, watershed

I have segmented my image using the Watershed algorithm, the result is pretty satisfying.
Now, I would like to extract and store what has been segmented but I don't really know how to do it.

Do you guys have an idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: After applying the watershed algorithm I tryed a findContour but the result is not what I was expecting.
What do you suggest ?

Comment: This question is difficult for me to understand.  You are asking how your code could be modified so that something is stored?

Comment: I have segmented the image using watershed algorithm. I would like to be able, for instance, to isolate the foreground from the background

Comment: You said that `findContour` did not give you the expected result. Can you describe what result you expected? Was the contour just wrong? Or do you want some other representation? Maybe a copy of the image with masked background pixels? Or a list of foreground pixels? There are lots of different possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is what I get after the watershed segmentation : http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/3713/capturedu20130404184128.png. We can see that the background is gray whereas the foreground is whit but it is store as one image. I'd like to get 2 differents images, one containing the background and the other containing the foreground. 

Does that make sense ? Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do a connected component analysis(8 connectedness) on the output image based on the color / index information. I think that would give you the easiest starting point. 
All the pixels in the neighborhood which are in the same segment and you can store that information and further use it.

However I don't think you can do background/foreground segmentation based on watershed as that requires a little more information than just segments for each frame. You will have to somehow keep a track of previous frame information too. There are a lot of papers. Go through them. Grimmson's paper was seminal. I've seen a lot more these days. Pixel Based Adaptive Segmenter was the best but very slow, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know what is connected component analysis. I'll look for it, it could be interresting ! 
thank you